# Il y a cinq quoi?

Tags: questions, interrogative

Je cherche une reformulation de

> Il y a cinq quoi?

qui est commune à l'oral mais que je me vois mal écrire.  J'ai quelques pistes, mais toutes me semblent au mieux lourdes, au pire bancales.

Comment: Peux-tu ajouter le contexte ? Je pense qu'il faut répondre de façon plus générale pour éviter cette formulation lourde...

Comment: Un jeu dont le but est de retrouver ce qui est en _n_ exemplaires dans une image.

Comment: Du coup, est-ce qu'une phrase du style "Quel [objet/élément/...] est présent cinq fois dans l'image" pourrait correspondre ?

Comment: J'en vois cinq, mais c'est quoi (ces cinq là) ?

Comment: @cl-r ça fait un peu enfantin non ? :p

Comment: @Random -- C'est peut-être une réponse qui reste dans le domaine de la question ; après tout l'âme enfantine est riche, créative, c'est souvent un trésor que la mémoire retrouve quand elle commence à vaciller, et puis *Un francophone* a précisé qu'il s'agit d'un jeu :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De façon assez générale:

> Qu'y a-t-il en cinq exemplaires ?

Mais je suis d'accord, en bon grammairiens, il nous faudrait inventer un pronom interrogatif pour ça, car il y en a beaucoup…

Comment: Excellente réponse, mais je ne vois pas l'utilité d'avoir un nouveau pronom, le "qu' " de "quoi" est parfaitement indiqué. Je ne comprends pas ce que tu as voulu dire.

Answer (score 4):

Quelque chose comme :

> Qu'est-ce qui apparaît cinq fois dans l'image ?

ou

> Qu'est ce qu'il y a cinq fois ?

ou

> Qu'est ce qui est représenté cinq fois ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce, petit oubli: le tiret. Une façon de le dire encore mieux, d'une façon plus formelle est donnée en par Stéphane. Qu'est-ce qu'il y a 5 fois? = Qu'y a-t-il 5 fois?

Answer (score 3):

Effectivement, sans le contexte, ou des pistes, c'est un peu plus dur de répondre. Et ça doit être utilisé dans un jeu? Une devinette? Une histoire pour enfant?

Si c'est une devinette. "Il y a 5 quoi?" est tout à fait admissible.
Si c'est par exemple dans un roman, et qu'une personne dit "il y a 5..." et qu'une autre qui a mal compris lui répond "il y a 5 quoi?", c'est aussi tout à fait admissible.
Si c'est pour un énoncé plus formel, par exemple, un exercice, "Dites quel est l'objet qui est reproduit 5 fois".

Désolée, je ne peux pas apporter de meilleure réponse en ce qui me concerne sans savoir de quoi il s'agit. C'est beaucoup trop flou.